# Making a Bitmap clickable using onTouchEvent - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I've created a SurfaceView and I've put an onTouchEvent on it, and the MotionEvent gets the whole screen, like this:

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if (!player.getPlaying()&& newGameCreated && reset) {
            player.setPlaying(true);
            player.fly(true);
            lives = 3;
        }
        if (player.getPlaying()) {
            if (!started) started = true;
            reset = false;
            player.fly(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        player.fly(false);
        return true;
    }

    // This is inside a class that extends SurfaceView

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And I need to check touch on bitmap or not using x-y position of touch and do a different action if the condition is true, how can I do this on this onTouchEvent method?

Comment: Have you added a Listener to the VIew where the Bitmap is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know coordinates of bitmap, his height and width. If you know all of it you can declare method:

```
public boolean clickedOnBitmap(final int x, final int y) {
    return x > bitmap.x && x < bitmap.x + bitmap.width
            && y > bitmap.y && y< bitmap.y + bitmap.height;
}
```

Comment: okay, but in onTouchEvent method, do I have to use event.getY() and event.getX() ?